# jQuery write each character with formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, loops

let´s say I have a string in JavaScript:

```
var str = '<span class="color:red;">Hello</span> my name is <span class="color:red;">Julian</span>';
```

So I would like to print each 300ms one character so that it looks as if it is being entered. Sure I can make a for-loop for each character and print it inside an element, but the problem is the formatting. If I use the for-loop it will even print the span-tag separately, but that will causing problems.

How to print every character after a while with formatting?

Comment: Here's an answer that will help you with a working example: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8053891/1830114)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8053891/1830114

Answer (score 1):

This quite an evil trick but you can use a white div on top of your string and move it step by step every 300ms. In this way a letter appears every 300ms. The only problem is to determine how big each step needs to be since the width of each character will vary.

A way to determine the width is to load all the characters separate in a div and measure the width. Of course you first need to strip the html. In order to so you could use [How to strip HTML tags with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140043/how-to-strip-html-tags-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You could split all characters into an array and then loop like this:

```
var str = '<span class="red">Hello</span> my name &nbsp; is <span class="red">Julian</span>',
    AllChars = [],
    SetTxt = true,
    newstr = '';

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    newstr += str.substr(i,1);
    if((str.substr(i,1) == '<') || (str.substr(i,1) == '&')){
        SetTxt = false;
    }else if(SetTxt){
        AllChars.push(newstr);
    }else if((str.substr(i,1) == '>') || (str.substr(i,1) == ';')){
        if(str.length == (i+1)){
            AllChars.push(newstr);
        }
        SetTxt = true;
    } 
}

for (var i in AllChars){
    setTimeout(function(i){
        $('#text').html(AllChars[i]);
    },300 * i,i); 
}
```

Check the jsfiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/2R9Dk/1/

Comment: Hey :) Wow, that is awesome! But there are two things I don´t undestand: 1.) Why is the last character replaced? For example "Julian" will be "Julia". 2.) Why does it work without </span>? I don´t see that you close the tags in AllChars. Do you believe all browsers close the tag itself?

Comment: I see there is a problem with HTML-characters. For example if you put &nbsp; inside the string it will write &nbsp; without formatting it

Comment: Hi, I changed the code. It will show the last character and closes the span tag. I also added support of the &nbsp; tag, if you want support for more html tags you have to add them for support. I've updated the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2R9Dk/1/ I Hope this helps point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse html tags and text separately. Something like:

```
var str = '<span class="colored">Hello</span> my name is <span class="colored bold">Julian</span>';      

function printTextByLetter(text, selector, speed) {
    var html = text.match(/(<[^<>]*>)/gi),
        sel = selector || 'body',
        arr = text.replace(/(<[^<>]*>)/gi, '{!!}').match(/(\{!!\}|.)/gi),
        counter = 0, cursor = jQuery(sel), insideTag,
        interval = setInterval(printChar, speed);       
    function printChar() {
        if(arr[0]){            
            if(arr[0] === '{!!}') {
                if(!insideTag) {
                    insideTag = true;
                    cursor.append(html[0], html[1]);
                    html.shift();
                    html.shift();
                    cursor = cursor.children().eq(counter);    
                } else {
                    insideTag = false;
                    cursor = cursor.parent();
                    counter++;        
                }                
            } else {
                cursor.append(arr[0]);    
            }
            arr.shift();            
        } else {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }
}        
// DOM ready
jQuery(function($){    
    printTextByLetter(str, '#target', 300);    
});
```

And don't forget to clear intervals - it does affect performance.

Example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/36kLf/7/